# What is the molecularity of a reaction if it has a fractional order as per rate equation?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

The rate equation of any reaction is found by using its slowest step.
My book says that molecularity of the slowest step of a reaction is equal to the order of the same reaction.
However, there are some reactions with fractional order but molecularity cannot be fractional.
Please tell whether my book is wrong or not.

Comment: "molecularity of the slowest step of a reaction is equal to the order of the same reaction" - it's generally not true.

Answer (score 3):

Fractional order happens in reactions like  $$\ce{H_2  +  Br_2  <=> 2 HBr}$$ for which Bodenstein and Lind found in 1906 their results in agreement with the empirical equation :$$\frac{d[HBr]}{dt} = \frac{k[H_2][Br_2]^{1/2}}{1 + k'[HBr]/[Br_2]}$$ Thirteen years later, this kinetics law was explained by Christiansen, Herzfeld and Polanyi in terms of the following chain mechanism $$\ce{Br_2 -> 2 Br}$$$$\ce{Br + H_2 -> HBr + H}$$$$\ce{H + Br_2 -> HBr + Br}$$$$\ce{H + HBr -> H_2 + Br}$$$$\ce{2 Br->Br_2}$$Each of these equations has its own rate constant. If you want to know how to use them to establish the results from Bodenstein and Lind, it is a long job, that I will not develop here. Please read the original publications.

J.A. Christiansen, Kgl. Danske Videnskab, Selskab., Mat.-fys. Med., 1. 14 (1919) ; 
K.F. Herzfeld, Ann. Physik, 59, 635 (1919) ; M. Polanyi, Z. Elektrochem., 26, 50 (1920)

Comment: Please tell whether my book is wrong or right.